# DPDK KNI example

Tags: dpdk

I want to work with DPDK for packet processing I can't run kni example
I tried every possible config and I get :

> EAL: Error - exiting with code: 1 
>   Cause: Invalid option specified

```
./build/kni -c 0x0f -n 4 -- -P -p 0x3 -config="(0,2,3),(1,4,5)"
./build/kni -c 0x0f -n 4 -- -P -p 0x3 -config="(0,4,6),(1,5,7)"
```

Comment: my bad missed a "-" before config, Funny

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I should put a "--" before config, but in all samples it has one dash

Answer (score 0):

Your command has en error:

```
./build/kni -c 0x0f -n 4 -- -P -p 0x3 -config="(0,4,6),(1,5,7)"
```

The -P option should put before -config, like this:

`-c 0x0f -n 4 -- -p 0x3 -P --config="(0,4,6),(1,5,7)"`

Answer (score 0):

From DPDK sample application user guide:

to run the application with two ports served by six lcores, one lcore of RX, one
lcore of TX, and one lcore of kernel thread for each port:
./build/kni -c 0xf0 -n 4 -- -P -p 0x3 -config="(0,4,6,8),(1,5,7,9)"

you need to check your "config" inputs(should be 4 elements for each port).

Answer (score 0):

the following command will work

```
./build/kni  -l 4-5  -n 4 -- -p1 -P --config="(0, 4, 5)"
```